# How do you compute a regular expression which is the intersection of two other regular expressions?

Tags: python, string

Consider the following two regular expressions:

> 1. `[ab][0123]`
> 2. `[bc][2345]`

What function will output the intersection of the two inputs without using `?=`

The following is not an acceptable output for our applications:

```python
(?=[ab][0123])(?=[bc][2345])
```

For my example, the correct output would be `[b][23]`

feel free to assume that we only use character classes and quantifiers with no negative look-behinds or fancy things.

Comment: I don't think there are any built-in functions for manipulating regular expressions like this. And in general, algebra of regular expressions is not a straightforward process. It may be possible with mathematical regular expressions (which are much simpler), but not the kinds of regular expressions used in programming.

Comment: For something trivial such as the regexes in your question you could parse the two expressions and combine the character sets. But IRL all you can really do is check inputs against both regular expressions; that will be the equivalent of testing against the intersection.

Comment: Also somewhat related, but not giving a procedure for determining it: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/106864/is-intersection-used-in-regular-expression.

Comment: What does this have to do with python?

Comment: Even *checking* whether a given proposed regex met the requirements seems like it would be Turing-complete, never mind actually coming up with a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: this answer only works as, if you put it in your question, we are "free to assume that we only use character classes and quantifiers with no negative look-behinds or fancy things", that is, we only allow characters (`a`), concatenation (`ab`), disjunction (`a|b`), repetition (`a*`) and optionality (`?`). Usual basic features of regular expressions (such as character classes (`[ab]`), numbered repetition (`a+`, `a{1,5}`, ...), ...) can be derived from these basic constructions, but it is impossible, for instance, to achieve backreferences (`\1`) in this framework.

Regular expressions are a very well studied topic, so your question has a "canonical" answer. I will not give the exact algorithm here, as it requires several steps which are quite long to properly implement (to give you an idea, a Python "working" implementation can be done in a few hundred lines, but an actual implementation, with a proper interface, unicode compatible, ... is more about 1,5k lines); however, each of the is pretty well documented and googling it should easily give you pointers.

1. Convert the regular expression to a non-deterministic automaton. There are several ways to do this, usually either using the [Thompson algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction) or the [Berry-Sethi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glushkov%27s_construction_algorithm) (the former being more intuitive, the second giving *slightly* better automata).
2. Convert the non-deterministic automaton to a deterministic one using the [powerset algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction).
3. Make the deterministic automaton *complete* by adding a sink state, and by adding any missing transition to point to the sink state. This step can even be skipped with proper bookkeeping.
4. Once you have done all this for *both* regular expressions, you can compute the product automaton (there is no wikipedia page for this construction, so I will give you [this stackoverflow question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/71362/product-construction-for-given-two-finite-automata) as reference hoping that it provides enough other references if you need them), where the accepting states in the product automaton are the couples of accepting states (that is, you are in an accepting state iff both the underlying states are accepting).
5. You can now go back to a regular expression, using [Kleene's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_algorithm).

As a side note, if performance *is* more important than implementation simplicity, you can skip determinisation of the automaton (which is the heaviest step), use the Berry-Sethi algorithm which produces no ϵ-transitions, and apply the rest of the procedure as-is (note that each step of the algorithm is slightly more complicated on non-deterministic automata).

Also note that you might want to insert an automaton [minimization procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization) before converting the automaton to a regular expression, otherwise you might end up with very, *very* ugly results.